# PARSE and BITCODE warning in XCODE 7

Tags: parse-platform, ios9, xcode7

In my app I use Parse.....till xcode6 and is everything is OK.
Yesterday I update in Xcode 7 and i try to build my app in Xcode 7 and I got the following warning :
"full bitcode bundle could not be generated because ParseUI.framework/ParseUI(PFLogInViewController.o) was built only with bitcode marker. The library must be generated from Xcode archive build with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE)"

Mention that in my Xcode 7 I have already enable BITCODE and I use last PARSE SDK 1.8.5
Can you help me please..

George Gerardis

Answer (score 0):

You have to **disable** `BITCODE` in Parse's target's `build settings`

It's used by developers to slim down app's ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html))

You will have to wait for `Parse` to release a new version with `bit code` enabled.